# Scrollspy not working on my wordpress site (possibly z-index issue?)

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, z-index, scrollspy

I have looked for an answer to this question to no avail. Hoping I can get some help from this community! I am trying to add the scrollspy feature of bootstrap to the navigation of my wordpress site. I have had some weird issues with z-index'ing and was thinking that might have something to do with it.

**What I want to happen:**
As the navbar becomes fixed to top after scroll, I would like to apply an active class to the link that is currently being scrolled over. example= as i scroll past the 'get involved' section, I want that item in the navbar to be highlighted according to whatever css rules I program.

**What is happening:**
The active class is only being applied sporadically, and not necessarily to the appropriate element. It's as if scrollspy isn't recognizing the id of the section it is scrolling over.

I'm pasting in the relevant section of code:

```
<body class="home blog logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support chrome" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".main-nav">
     <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '277595855720684',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.2'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.
    </div>
    <![endif]-->
    <style type="text/css">
      a.navbar-brand {background-image:url(http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/logo_nav.png);}
      @media
        only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
        only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
          a.navbar-brand {background-image:url(http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/logo_nav.png);}
      }

      #p2p, #why-attend, #schedule, #register, #video, #twitter-updates, #attendees, #venue, #venue_head #polls, #quote-two, #quote-three, #quote-four, #home {
        z-index: 977 !important;
      }

    </style>

    <div class"vid-background">
      <video autoplay loop id="bgvid">
        <source src="http://cssummit.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Summit-Header-Video-v4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="http://cssummit.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Summit-Header-Video_bw.webm" type="video/webm">
      </video>
    </div>
    <section id="home" style="background-image:url();"><!-- this section closes in home.php-->




    <style type="text/css">
      .hero-logo {background-image:url(http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/cssummit_logo.png);}
      @media
        only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
        only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
          .hero-logo {background-image:url(http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/cssummit_logo.png);}
      }
      /****************************/
      #nav.affix {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%
      }
      /****************************/
    </style>
    <!--<div class="container hero">
      <div class="row row-offcanvas">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
          <div class="hero-logo center-block"></div><p class="hero-copy">Successes. Failures. Lessons learned. We improve through the collective <strong>Power of Us</strong>. Attend the industry-leading Customer Success event for SaaS and subscription businesses.</p>      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://events.mfactormeetings.com/12845" target="_blank">Register Now</a>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.row -->
    <!--</div><!-- /.container -->

    <div class="container hero">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <img class="img-responsive mobile-hide" src="http://cssummit.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/cssummit-header-logo_03.png" style="position:relative;top:-15px;left:-15px;">
          <img class="img-responsive mobile-show" src="http://cssummit.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/mobile-header-large-better.png" style="position:relative;top:-15px;left:-15px;display:none;">
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
        <div id="header-social-mobile" style="display:none;position:relative;top:-295px;left:55px;width:275px;">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/customersuccesssummit/" target="blank"><img src="http://cssummit.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/fb_icon.png"></a>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23CSSUmmit16&src=typd" target="blank"><img src="http://cssummit.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/twitter_icon.png"></a>
          <a href="" style="display:none;"><img src="http://cssummit.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/in_icon.png"></a>
        </div>
    <div id="header-social">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/customersuccesssummit/" target="blank"><img src="http://cssummit.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/fb_icon.png"></a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23CSSUmmit16&src=typd" target="blank"><img src="http://cssummit.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/twitter_icon.png"></a>
      <a href="" style="display:none;"><img src="http://cssummit.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/in_icon.png"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center hero-body" style="position: relative;bottom: 40px;">
      <h1 class="header-h1" style="clear:both;text-align:center;color:#fff;font-size:52px;">MASTERING THE BUSINESS OF CUSTOMER SUCCESS</h1>
      <h2 class="text-center header-h2" style="color:#fff;font-size:40px;">MARCH 21-22 | SAN FRANCISCO</h2>
      <h2 class="text-center header-h2-m" style="color:#fff;font-size:40px;display:none;">MARCH 21-22 <br> SAN FRANCISCO</h2>
      <a class="btn btn-custom btn-mobile reg-mobile-hide" style="background-color:#b2d33f;margin-top:25px;color:#2f2f2f;padding:17px 50px;" href="#register" >REGISTER NOW</a>
      <a class="btn btn-custom btn-mobile reg-mobile-show" style="background-color:#b2d33f;margin-top:25px;color:#2f2f2f;padding:17px 50px;display:none;" href="https://www.eventbrite.com/e/customer-success-summit-2016-registration-19312168215" >REGISTER NOW</a>
      <p style="padding-top:40px;"><a href="#nav"><img id="mobile-arrow-hide" src="http://cssummit.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/arrow_down_hero_image.png"></a></p>
    </div>  
    </section><!-- /#home (opens in header.php)-->
      <div id="nav">
        <div class="container main-nav">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".lower-navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand text-hide" href="#home">Customer Success Summit 2015</a>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-header -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse lower-navbar nav"> 
              <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-14"><a href="#why-attend">Why Attend</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-15"><a href="#p2p">Get Involved</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-16"><a href="#partners">Sponsor</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-17"><a href="#venue_head">Venue</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-18"><a href="#register">Register</a></li>
    </ul>        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: try changing the data-target in the body tag to .navbar

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I have tried to use .navbar, .main-nav, and #nav. I can see an active class being applied to certain sections, but not necessarily while I'm scrolling over them (i.e. the Register nav item is .active when I'm at the top of the page). Scrollspy is trying to work, just not properly. Has anyone ever heard of z-indexes or relative positioning affecting scrollspy?? THANKS!!